# How to get the first child id inside the div using JQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

How to get the first child id inside the div using JQuery.

Sample code:

```
<div id='id1'>
    <a id='a1' />   
    <a id='a2' /> 
    <a id='a3' /> 
</div>
```

I want to get the id `a1`.

I have tried `$('#id1 a:first-child').html()` to get the text. How to get the id?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$("#id1:first-child").attr("id")
```

Comment: `.attr('id')` will get the id

Comment: This will give you the id of the id1 element and not its first child. To get the first div child I used #id1 div:first-child. So #id1 a-child will give the first a child's id.

Comment: I don't know why people are upvoting this answer 22 upvotes ?? why. This actually selects first Child element with id - 'id1' and query is to select 'a' element under another parent div

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla almost 9 years later you you comment on this like this, it obviously worked at the time. Now, while I can't recall, something may have changed in the API at some point, but I think you comment is also incorrect. Maybe test it out an post a fiddle.

Comment: @DustinLaine Okay Sorry to annoy you for the comment but i actually i want to notify in comment to other users

Answer (score 19):

Use this to get first element of id1 element:

```
    $("#id1").children(":first");
```

Answer (score 14):

Below Answer Will Select First 'a' Element under element With ID - 'id1" ( As per Asked in Question )

```
$('#id1 a:first-child').attr('id')
```

Below Code will only Select First Div with ID - 'id1' So it will select that div not child element of div ( But its not as per asked by question in answer )

```
$('#id1:first-child').attr('id')
```

Comment: He wants the ID of the first anchor (a1). This would give him the first child of the first anchor. It would be (a2).

Comment: for some reason, your code won't work with me. I get always undefined.
and the piece of code that i wrot gives me the first id (a1) and not a2. if i read this: http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/ I asume that my code will search at the first "<a ../>" in the div "id1" ...
correct me if i'm wrong..
bruno

Answer (score 5):

If you want immediate first child you need

```
$(element).first();
```

If you want particular first element in the dom from your element then use below

```
var spanElement = $(elementId).find(".redClass :first");
$(spanElement).addClass("yourClassHere");
```

try out : http://jsfiddle.net/vgGbc/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id1:first-child').attr('id')
```

Comment: See my response to @bruno's comment. Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To make things super clear, this is what to do in order to find any element within a certain element you already can access, in this case that is the element with id='e1':

```
<style>
  .c1{ border:2px solid red; padding: 12px; background: lightyellow }
  .c2{ border:2px solid green; padding: 12px; background: lightyellow }
  .c3{ border:2px solid blue; padding: 12px; background: lightyellow }
</style>

<div class='c1' id='e1'>
  <div class='c2' id='e2'>
    <div class='c3' id='e3'>text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following line get's you div e2:

```
var child2 = $('#e1').find(".c2");
```

The following lines both get you div e3:

```
var child3   = $('#e1').find(".c3");
var child3_1 = $('#e1').find(".c2 :first");
```

To change something about these, you have to use the objects like this:

```
$(child2).css('background-color','white');
$(child3).css('border','4px dotted pink');
$(child3_1).css('color','#ef2323');
```

I hope this is clear and helpful.

Edit: This comment should be removed because it provides no value.

Answer (score 0):

$("#form .form-group").first();

May be helpful for someone.