# How to get first ID of nested element with Jquery

Tags: jquery

This should exactly answer my question:

[How to get the first child id inside the div using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400076/how-to-get-the-first-child-id-inside-the-div-using-jquery)

but when I try it is returning the ID of the parent element itself. The html I have is:

```
<div id="top-right-container">
    <div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="products">
        <div class="product-heading">
            <h4 class="product-title">Products</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="product-body">
            <span class="product-text">Product</span>
            <div>
                <div id="product-element"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the js I am using is:

```
var topRightContainer = $("#top-right-container:first-child").attr("id");
var bottomRightContainer = $("#bottom-right-container:first-child").attr("id");
console.log(topRightContainer);
```

The output to the console is "top-right-container"

Comment: What result should returned?

Comment: I am trying to get the id of this element: <div id="product-element"></div>

Comment: @Mike - if you want `product-element`.. you can target using `$("#top-right-container div.product-body div div").attr("id");` It is ugly, if you add a class or a data attribute to the `product-element` div, it will be easier

Comment: The first child of `#top-right-container` does not have an `id` attribute. Are you trying to retrieve the the `data-sortable-id` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the right answer which is the id of the first child of the `#top-right-container`

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/o4fwk3k8/2/)

```
var topRightContainer = $("#top-right-container div:first-child").attr("id");
alert(topRightContainer);
```