# jQuery first node selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

I have a wrapper element, which contains child elements with unique is's.
How does one get the an element without having to traverse?

eg.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="child1">content</div>
    <div id="child2">content</div>
    <div id="child3">content</div>
</div>
```

I am currently using a jQuery.find, but still unable to find only one and first element.

```
$("#wrapper").find("#child1")......
```

The code above is not returning the child element specified inside the find function parameter but an array, containing only child1. Thus resulting to write code like this.

```
$("#wrapper").find("#child1").each(function(){//do something...});
```

PS: I would really like to avoid something like this as it is inefficient

```
$("#wrapper #child1")
```

As I have the #wrapper element already and do not want to traverse over the entire DOM once again.

Comment: Like this: `$('#wrapper > div:first')`

Comment: Do you want to find the element `child1`? cant you use something like `$('#wrapper:first-child')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select first child with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852452/how-to-select-first-child-with-jquery) and [How to get the first child id inside the div using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400076) and [How to Access First Child Div of the Parent Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043020)

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: Please spend some time having a cursory read of the jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com Even just reading the method names gives you a good idea of what they do

Comment: Hi RoryMcCrossan. Not just the first element, but every single one of them, without having to traverse.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first element you can use children and refer to the first element

```js
console.log($("#wrapper").children()[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="child1">content</div>
  <div id="child2">content</div>
  <div id="child3">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the child elements with unique IDs, you can directly access that element by the id.

```
$("#child1").css('color', 'red');
```

or if you want to use jQuery, you can make use of the jQuery's children method.

```
$('#wrapper').children('#child1');
```

Comment: Hi, I do not want jQuery to look over the entire DOM once again. I already have the wrapper element inside a variable.

Comment: In that case you can use wrapperVariable.children('#child1')

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#wrapper div:first-child").css("color","green");
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to leave a note about why this is the right solution.¨

Comment: What's that color setting needed for? I haven't found any information about that in the question

Comment: The author made a special note that the `#wrapper` element is already known and it is undesirable to search for it again.

Answer (score -2):

You can use :first-child selector

```
$( "#wrapper:first-child" )
```